# Parent block doesn't shrink after children wrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What it looks like: 
[image: SS]

When I decrease the browser's window size I get:
[image: SS]

BUT I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE THIS **WITHOUT USING FLEXBOX**:

[image: SS]

Here's [codepen](http://codepen.io/Manidos/pen/gMraqa)

**CODE:**

```css
#one {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
#two {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want the light-grey box centered inside the grey box?

Comment: @Roysh, I want black squares to be centered like in the third picture I posted. Background-color of parent divs don't matter to me.

Comment: Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gj2ub837/

Comment: @Roysh you reproduced my results in your jsfiddle. The problem is that when you decrease the width of the window black squares collapse and are no longer centered. I'm afraid there's only one way - to use media queries

Comment: well, if you don't mind the square to get shrinked on lower resolutions, you can use ration width instead of media queries, like I made in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gj2ub837/1/

Comment: @Roysh The problem there is that black squares are still not centered relative to darkgrey div. Anyway, many many thanks, good sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `Flexbox`, you need `@media queries`  for that.

changed your values to make it responsive

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
#one {
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0 /* inline-block gap fix */
}
#two {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin:5px
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .square {
    width:calc((100% / 2) - 10px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, dude! Thank you so much! Especially, for "inline-block gap fix" — I thought there were no cure for that.

Comment: You're the best person to ask. What does *::before, *::after do? Are they simply selectors for all pseudo-elements :before and :after?

Comment: I would advise you to read this article about `box-sizing` [article](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#two {
display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width:100%;
}
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32.5%;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using Media queries [codepen](http://codepen.io/Manidos/pen/xOVgwp)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
#one {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
#two {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
  #two {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #two {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```